# else if not working and first if always return true even select other option

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I make a function to return int based on COUNT, but else if not working. Could I miss something?

```
   function kv_get_task_count() {
    global $wpdb;


            if (filter_status('new')):
                $count_post = (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts
                                            WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND post_status ="new"
                                            ' );
            elseif (filter_status('pending_review')): 
                $count_post =  (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts
                                            WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND post_status ="pending_review"
                                            ' );
            else:
                $count_post =  (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts
                                            WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND post_status ="new"
                                                OR post_status ="pending_review"
                                            ' );
            endif;  

            return $count_post;
}
```

Comment: what is the output of `filter_status('pending_review')`

Comment: for last query use braces : `WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND  (post_status ="new"
                                                OR post_status ="pending_review")`

Comment: @AswinRamesh output filter_status is all list from  function kv_get_task_count() only to count results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUESTION CLOSE !!

I change my code to:

```
   function kv_get_task_count() {
    global $wpdb;


            if ($_REQUEST['post_status'] == 'new'):
                $count_post = (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts
                                            WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND post_status ="new"
                                            ' );
            elseif ($_REQUEST['post_status'] == 'pending_review'): 
                $count_post =  (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts
                                            WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND post_status ="pending_review"
                                            ' );
            else:
                $count_post =  (int) $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts
                                            WHERE post_type ="screening"
                                                AND post_status ="new"
                                                OR post_status ="pending_review"
                                            ' );
            endif;  

            return $count_post;
}
```